Can modern CPU architectures exploit FIR symmetry
It's been a while since I've read on computer architecture. But I remember my CPU classes where we looked at the Harvard architecture. So basically it got me wondering whether or we can actually make symmetrical FIR filters faster than non-symmetrical FIR filters. I've also done a lot of FPGA design, with in an FPGA it's pretty easy to take advantage of symmetrical and anti-symmetrical FIR filters and reduce the number of multipliers by 2 compared to a non-symmetrical FIR filter.
Assuming that we have a symmetrical FIR filter with an even number of coefficients, I have 3 implementations
First implementation that does not consider FIR symmetry
double output = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < NB_COEFS; i++)
{
    output += data[i]*COEFS[i];
}

Second implementation- Taking advantage of the FIR symmetry
double output = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < NB_COEFS/2; i++)
{
    output += (data[i]+data[NB_COEFS-i])*COEFS[i];
}

Third implementation- performing the pre-addition separately
float preadd[NB_COEFS/2];
double output = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < NB_COEFS/2; i++)
{
   preadd[i] = data[i] + data[NB_COEFS-i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < NB_COEFS/2; i++)
{
    output += preadd[i]*COEFS[i];
}

Can the second or third implementation be faster than the first one? My gut intuition tells me that because of the Harvard architecture, it's unlikely.

I think your perfectly symmetrical FIR will have an odd number of non-zero coefficients.

oh, if you don't assume "zero phase" or a linear-phase FIR filter with an integer sample delay, then I guess your symmetrical FIR can have an even number of coefficients.  But the delay will be some integer plus 1/2 sample.

Last time I worked at the CPU level data flow was at least as important than multipliers. Single cycle multipliers are pretty common these days and vector processing units have a a bunch of them. The simple FIR version has the advantage that data and coefficients are accessed strictly in order, which most memory management units prefer. So it really depends on what exact architecture you are looking at: ARM vs, a real DSP vs.  SIMD etc.

I have an ARM CPU. The previous architecture was a DSP, in the previous architecture, we "took advantage" of the filter symmetry but AFAIK no measurements were performed to validate whether or not we actually gained something.

@robertbristow-johnson  : You're right, but I wanted to simplify the question a bit by not including the "outlier" coefficient.

If you're doing this with an ARM and in C, then I think you might save a memory access (fetching the coefficient once instead of twice), the way you're doing this.  But make this one loop, instead of two.

Even for a given ARM core, there's so many possible ways a manufacturer could implement memory interfaces, cache, and even memory, I think optimization would be case by case.

Yes, a modern CPU can make use of that structure – but probably less in the way you expect!
So, first of all: saying "I have an ARM" is not sufficient – that's a huge family of ISAs, and some have extensions for floating point (for example, armv7-*) vectorized operations (vector floating point, NEON, Helium). I'll assume you mean one of these (aarch64 armv8 & NEON) when you say "modern processor". Things you often find in ARM microcontrollers (ARM Cortex-M{0,0+,1,3,4,7}) aren't really "modern" architectures.
As with modern x86 processors, the memory bottleneck is very real with these; halving the amount of memory that you get from RAM is a good deal!
Your preadding trickery will not be very useful, however: addition of floating point numbers isn't faster than multiplication (at least, in general), and: there's vector instructions where you can load 4 coefficients at once, and multiply them with 4 data values exist on both ARMv7 / v8 and x86 SIMD, as do "horizontal sums" that reduce 4 of these values to one. And if you can pack the values more closely, for example by using a 32 bit floating point type instead of your 64 bit doubles, your CPU might even be able to do 8 in parallel (AVX2 on x86), or even 16 (AVX-512). And the best part: your modern C/C++ compiler (gcc, clang) sees for(unsigned i = 0; i < 256; ++i) sum += coeffs[i]*data[i]; and it will definitely put multiple of the available SIMD width into SIMD registers, do the SIMD multiplication and reduction; see this example based on your code. The NEON "multiply element-wise" instruction is fmul vREG.sub, vREG.sub, vREG.sub, and the the "add all elements" instruction is faddp ….
When you look at what the compiler does for your "straightforward" FIR is pretty much this:

take 4 coefficients, put them in a vector register
take 4 data values, put them in another vector register
multiply these two vectors element-wise, save result in one of the vector registers
check whether you've reached the end of your vector, if so, jump to 10.
take the next 4 coefficients, load them
take the next 4 data values, load them
multiply element-wise
add the resulting vector to the saved values from step 3.
jump to 4.
add the four partial sums to get the final sum

You'll notice two things:

this is taking only one fourth of the multiplication and addition instructions that your "textbook" FIR implementation would have,
the loads in steps 5. and 6. are very "dumb" and march forward all the time, ignoring symmetry

You could of course modify step 4. to check for half the coefficient number, and afterwards swap the direction with which you jump 4 coefficients addresses. This would be nice – you reduce the memory cache usage by half. Whether or not this really brings a benefit depends on your caches and memory controller – in general, loading cachelines consecutively both in up- and downwards direction can lead to good prefetching, but it's not a given. And whether or not your data loading thrashes all your cache anyway is really impossible to know without taking a really deep look at your specific CPU and your problem sizes. The problem you inherit with exploiting the symmetry is that for loading the vector register with coefficients, you need to add an extra shuffle, to reorder the elements from that vector. And these shuffles, both on ARM and x86, take time, depending really on the generation of the processor. They might totally be hidden by doing the data loading while the shuffle is done, they might dominate the computational cost!
Now, a good argument here would be that your coefficients vector is bound to be small compared to CPU caches, anyways. How do I know, without you having told us? Because otherwise, doing a time-domain FIR would be a folly, anyways, and you go for an overlap-save (or -add) FFT-accelerated approach anyways. The FFT is at the other extreme than the "straightforward" FIR implementation: by its very principle, it requires the CPU to jump around in memory quite a bit, so it only pays when the complexity savings ($\propto\log N$ instead of $\propto N$ operations per output sample) outweigh the wild access scheme penalty you pay.
Now, if you're doing an FFT-based convolution, you'll need to transform your coefficients vector to DFT domain; and you'll notice that a time-symmetrical real vector is purely real after DFT, which means you can save yourself complex×complex multiplications in the discrete frequency domain, and do less-than-half-as-intense real×complex multiplications, before transforming your signal back.

I believe that you can do a vrev() instruction rather than shuffle() for this purpose?

@KnutInge "shuffle" was meant to describe the class of instructions, which you'd find on most vectorized architectures, from altivec to NEON to SSE…

double output = 0.0;
for (int i=0; i<NB_COEFS/2; i++)
{
   double preadd = data[i] + data[(NB_COEFS-1)-i];
   output += preadd*COEFS[i];
}

This does not deal with circular buffer (memory wrap-around) issues with the data[] buffer.  There are multiple ways to deal with it.
This is a symmetrical FIR and about as basic as one can do.  The wrap-around arithmetic for a FIFO buffer index is done by bit masking which is why the BUFFERSIZE must be a power of two.  Bit masking for modulo arithmetic is almost always cheaper than the % operator.
double get_sample(void);
void put_sample(double);

#define NB_COEFS 50          // must be even
#define BUFFERSIZE 128       // must be a power of two

double data[BUFFERSIZE];
double coefs[NB_COEFS/2];

// The data[] buffer gets cleared and the coefs[] array gets loaded with coefs.



int input_index = 0;

while(TRUE)                   // loop forever
{
    double input = get_sample();
    data[input_index] = input;

    double output = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<(NB_COEFS/2); i++)
    {
       double preadd = data[(input_index-i)&(BUFFERSIZE-1)] + data[(input_index-(NB_COEFS-1)+i)&(BUFFERSIZE-1)];
       output += preadd*coefs[i];
    }

    input_index = (input_index+1)&(BUFFERSIZE-1);

    put_sample(output);
}

This is about as basic as you can get for an FIR.

I find that in software, "arithmetic cost" tends to be more relevant than counting multipliers like we did back in university (1 add or sub costs '1'. One multiply costs '1'. One fused multiply-add costs '1'. One generic division costs 'a lot') in terms of throughput. Even more so, having a topology and code that lends itself to SIMD instructions can often give a speedup of 2/4/8/16/32 depending on datatypes and HW. At some point, the problem stops being about arithmetic and turns into a problem of cache behaviour and memory bandwidth.

Your first snippet does NB_COEFS - 1 adds and NB_COEFFS/2 multiplies ~= 1.5 x NB_COEFFS (arithmetic cost). A generic FIR implementation would do NB_COEFS - 1 adds and NB_COEFFS multiplies ~= 2 x NB_COEFFS of arithmetic cost, I believe.

I'm not saying it's really gonna save anything other than a little memory.  It fetches the coefficient once for two samples rather than twice.  The table for coefficients is half as large as it would normally be without symmetry.  I just didn't think the OP was doing it efficiently by making a table of preadd[.].  So I corrected that.  Then I realized I wasn't dealing with the sample data[.] FIFO correctly, so I fixed that.
